# how to convert all subdomain request to main domain, and keep url rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

hello I have a website with a main domain , and subdomains.. running over apache web server and centOS... I also have a url rewrite mechanism such as

**http://subdomain.domain.com/buy-a-new-car**

Id like to redirect all subdomain requests to main domain, keeping the url rewrite like this:

**http://domain.com/buy-a-new-car**

the .htaccess code i have so far results in this :

**http://domain.com/index.php?buy-a-new-car**

id like to get rid of the ( index.php? ) part, but I am new to writing .htaccess directives and confused by REGEX

here is my current code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your redirects to happen first, then at the end, do your routing to `index.php`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options -Indexes -Multiviews

# redirect subdomains to main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect direct accesses to index.php 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /index\.php\?/([^&\ ]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2 [L,R=301]

# route everything to index.php internally
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `Redirect` and/or `RedirectMatch` and save the Rewrite stuff for the real rewriting of URLs? See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html

I find this a much more "self documenting" approach which doesn't force you to understand all the rewrite logic each time you go in there.